# Kibana Dashboard Share without login

Tags: kibana

How can I view dashboards created in Kibana without logging in?
How to set it up in elastic cloud 8.5 but not in yml ?

Tried several methods but failed.

I can't find how to set it in version 8.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana APIs can help you

```
GET <kibana host>:<port>/s/<space-id>/api/kibana/dashboards/export
```

---

```
$ curl -X GET <kibana host>:<port>/api/kibana/dashboards/export?dashboard=942dcef0-b2cd-11e8-ad8e-85441f0c2e5c
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard-api-export.html